# Why Circuit error when I use append(U)

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

I am new of this field.

I want to make custom Unitary transform. I make a test matrix with Identity matrix.

If I use UnitaryGate and append it to main circuit, it would not work.

Here is my code.

**I know that main_circuit.unitary(matrix_U) works well.
But why main_circuit.append(U) does not work?**

```
from qiskit import*
from qiskit.extensions import UnitaryGate

matrix_U=[[1,0],[0,1]]
U=UnitaryGate(matrix_U)
main_circuit=QuantumCircuit(2,2)
main_circuit.append(U)
%matplotlib inline
main_circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to quantum computing StackExchange!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the quantum instruction, [`append()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.append.html) method expects the qubits to attach the instruction to.

So, in your case you should call it as follows:

```
main_circuit.append(U, [0])
```

Here, I applied the unitary to the first qubit, you can specify another qubit if you want. And if your unitary is a multi-qubit unitary, the list should contain $\log_2(N)$ qubits where $N$ is the matrix dimension.

Comment: Thanks, Now main_circuit.append(U,[0]) is working.

Answer (score 1):

For this small case, you dont need to use the `UnitaryGate` class (which is used with the `append` method as [Egretta.Thula described](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/29375/): `append(GateClass, [qubits])`). It is possible to give the matrix directly to `QuantumCircuit.unitary` and the amount of arguments are $log_2(\texttt{len(main_circuit)}$):

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

matrix_U=[[1,0],[0,1]]
main_circuit=QuantumCircuit(1)
main_circuit.unitary(matrix_U, 0)
main_circuit.draw(output='mpl')
```

[image: circuit with unitary]

Comment: That is a good alternative. Thanks